# Call window.print() with dynamically loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have separate pages that print their contents upon load.

I now want to create a new page, where upon load it prints the contents of 2 other printable pages (2 copies of bol, 1 copy of ps).

Body:

```
<body>
    <div class="bol"></div> 
    <br />
    <div class="bol"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="ps"></div>
</body>
```

This jQuery successfully loads the contents of the other pages in to their respective divs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bol').load('bolPrint.aspx');
    $('.ps').load('psPrint.aspx');
});
```

If I leave this, and then hit `File -> Print` or `ctrl + p` the print window appears with the 3 separate pages and it works perfectly. 
[image: working_example]
**However, I want this print window to appear on the initial page load.**

When I add window.print():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bol').load('bolPrint.aspx');
    $('.ps').load('psPrint.aspx');
    window.print();
});
```

or

```
<body onload='window.print()'>
```

the print preview doesn't contain any of the dynamically loaded content. It is just a blank page with the title info.
[image: broken_example]

Comment: Did you try to call print  in the load() callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the divs to load. Here I load the ps after successfully loading bol and print after successfully loading ps:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var cnt = $('.bol').length-1;
  $('.bol').load('bolPrint.aspx',function() {
    if (cnt==0) {
      $('.ps').load('psPrint.aspx',function() {
        window.print();
      });
    }
    cnt--;
  });
});
```

Comment: this works except that it is calling window.print() twice now because there are two div's with class = bol. Is there a way I can call the ps load & window.print ONLY ON the last bol load callback?

Comment: obviously I could use separate ID's for each div, or a counter to only call on the second time, but I'm wondering if there's maybe a way I could use a jQuery selector in the .bol load callback function to test if this is the last one in the elements selected by $('.bol')

Comment: Of course, I usually wait a day or so though to give other people a chance. (bullet 2 under "Which answer should I choose?")